# How to detect the any 4 sides polygen in the image and adjust it to rectangle?

Tags: iphone, linux, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

One TV screen recognition project, i need to clip the TV Screen from one image.

The TV screen actually is rectangle. But It's obvious that the TV screen is out of shape in the image from phone camera. My question are:

1. How to detect the any 4 sides polygen(it's not rectangle) in the image.
2. After i know the polygen area on the image ,how to retrieve the area to Mat.
3. After solve quest2, How to convert the Mat of 4 sides polygen to rectangle Mat which is fixed W/H radio.

It's very helpful that give some code sample to reference.

Thanks your answers!

Comment: 'Mat'? What do you mean by 'Mat', is it matrix?

Comment: Do you know the aspect ratio of the TV Screen?  When you say it is not a rectangle, do you mean it is a rectangle under perspective distortion or that it is not a rectangle at all?  The method for detecting the edges of the TV changes depending on what you can assume about the background.  Nobody will be able to help you much without knowing more about the image.

Comment: The scene is that i take picture to my home TV Screen. It's known TV Screen actual is rectangle. But it is trapezoid in my picture  because of perspective distortion. So that's problem ,how to detect the 4 sides polygen and convert it to original's rectangle.

Comment: You're probably going to want to use edge detection combined with a Hough transform to determine the lines that make up the borders of your rectangle. From there, you'll need to calculate the homography.

Comment: I'm facing this problem now, my first atempt has this, use canny and hough to get the lines, but I get lots of lines that not are part of the TV. I adapted somehow the squares example of OpenCV, but I still can't get the TV detected very well. Did you solve your problem @tihuBird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to detect the edges of your TV screen you can use some border
detection (like Canny) and then use Hough transform to obtained the lines.

If you then extract the points corresponding to the intersection of the lines
you can create an homography matrix H (3x3). Finally, using this homgraphy you can
"deform" your original image to a reference frame (in our case the rectangle
with a given aspect ratio). The homography is a transformation from plane
to plane, so it's exactly what you will need here.

If your going to use OpenCV (which is always a good choice!), 
here are the functions that you could use:

- Canny() - find edges in the image
- HoughLines() - detect lines
- findHomography() - this function finds from a set of correspondances,
  the homography matrix. In your case, you will need to pass the method
  as 0.
- warpPerspective() - the function that your going to use to "deform"
  the image to a reference frame.

Obviously, you can find similar functions for MATLAB and others...

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks,Hammer  Brad Larson and G.Fuhr. G.Fuhr have given the detail step ,it's very helpful. I'wll follow the steps to solve the problem.